# Arduino Ethernet Shield 2 not working

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I am currently trying to get the Ethernet Shield working on my Mega. I was trying to run the Webserver example but the program seems to stuck at one point, so I tried to start from scratch.

This is my test code:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

byte mac[] = {
  0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0F, 0xF6, 0x3D
};
byte subnet[] = { 255,0,0,0 };
byte gateway[] = { 2,0,0,1 };
IPAddress ip(2, 0, 0, 1);

EthernetServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
  Serial.println("Ethernet started");
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println("Loop");
}
```

The output I get from the serial console is:

```
Etrted
Ethernet started
```

So I think the program gets stuck inside the EthernetServer::begin() function.
I am aware that there are earlier versions of ethernet shields which are not compatible to the mega, but the vendor of my shield says it is.

Also I don't understand, why it outputs the first line.

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: you should try here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Arduino.cc and Arduino.org are not the same... Arduino.org, who is selling the ethernet shield 2, has their own IDE with the correct library! You can download it at http://www.arduino.org/downloads and the source can be found at https://github.com/arduino-org/Arduino/tree/1.7.4/libraries

Comment: It was not a library problem. Just cut all headers but the ICSP header of the shield off for about 2mm and it works.

Comment: Ok - I just experienced the exact same behavior as you which was fixed by using the correct library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code form (http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DhcpAddressPrinter):

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = {  
  0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDE, 0x02 };

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server 
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // this check is only needed on the Leonardo:
   while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    for(;;)
      ;
  }
  // print your local IP address:
  Serial.print("My IP address: ");
  for (byte thisByte = 0; thisByte < 4; thisByte++) {
    // print the value of each byte of the IP address:
    Serial.print(Ethernet.localIP()[thisByte], DEC);
    Serial.print("."); 
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {

}
```

And post what the serial monitor output is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

NB. You can reuse your code written for Arduino Ethernet Shield, simply replacing

```
#include <Ethernet.h>  -->  #include <Ethernet2.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>  -->  #include <EthernetUdp2.h>
```

See this: http://labs.arduino.org/Arduino+Ethernet+Shield+2